# Image pans out of the modal body when height and width is set

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using modal dialog for display single images of photo gallery in my application,

```
<div class="modal fade" id="example{{$index}}" role="dialog">
   .....
   <div class="modal-body">    
     <img ng-src="../Files/Photos/{{photo_item.link}}" width="565" height="370" />
   </div>
   .....
</div>
```

[image]

Now image has **width="565"** and **height="370"** and doesn't exit over border of **modal-dialog**,
but when i change values of width and height attributes :

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <img ng-src="../Files/Photos/{{photo_item.link}}" width="900" height="700" />
</div>
```

[image]
May be somebody knows how i can resolve it, or i can change values just in **bootstrap.css** file ?
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: have you tried to set the modal size to large by using css class "modal-lg"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use "img-responsive" class when you want an image that adjust to the width of the containing object.

If you want image that adjusts to the height then use

.img-responsive-ht

```
{
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%
}
```

note: remove the width and height that you mention in image tag image adjust itself w.r.t container

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the width and height and set it to 100% (both). Then image will stay inside modal box.

have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that is what you are looking for, but if you want the modal to be larger you could use:

```
<div class="modal modal-lg">
     <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
             <img ng-src="../Files/Photos/{{photo_item.link}}"/>   
          </div> 
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue add bootstrap's `img-fluid` class and remove other attributes of width and height.

So the code will look like this,

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <img ng-src="../Files/Photos/{{photo_item.link}}" class="img-fluid" />
</div>
```